# Why am I getting a break outside loop error for this python program but not for a similar program?

Tags: python, break

I am new to coding and Stack Exchange. Please forgive any errors  in terms of formatting questions (corrections are welcomed). My question is this. I am doing exercise 7-4 in "Python Crash Course". I have two programs that are very similar in terms of formatting and output. city_visits was the example given by the author and did not lead to a "break outside loop" error. However Pizza_toppings leads to a "break outside loop" error. Can anyone please explain what the difference is that leads to the error in one but not the other? Thanks for the help!

Pizza_toppings.py

```
prompt = "\nWelcome to Pizza by the sea!" 
prompt += "\nYou can add as manty toppings as you like! Just tell us!"
prompt += "\nWhen you are finished type 'quit'. Tell us what you want: "

while True:
topping = raw_input(prompt) 

if topping == "quit":
 break
else: 
    print "Adding " + topping + "."
```

city_visits

```
prompt = "\nPlease enter the name of a city you have visited:"
prompt += "\n(Enter 'quit' when you are finished.)"

while True:  
city = raw_input(prompt)

if city == 'quit':
    break
else:
    print "I'd love to go to " + city.title() + "!"
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up.

Comment: *This is madness...*   This is PYTHON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the scope of loops and `if/else` blocks is determined solely by indentation, so if your indentation is messed up -- as it seems to be the case in your code -- it will produce strange results, or not compile at all if certain elements like `break` are used in an unexpected context.

Your code, in both examples, should be indented like this:

```
while True:  
    city = raw_input(prompt)

    if city == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print "I'd love to go to " + city.title() + "!"
```

Note how `city`, `if`, and `else` are all (a) further indented than `while`, and (b) indented exactly the same amount. *How* you indent is not too important, but good practice dictates [4 spaces per level of indentation (although some prefer 1 tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119562/1639625). Also, never mix tabs and spaces, or your indentation may *look* correct in your editor, but in reality be totally messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is strict in Python. This:

```
if topping == "quit":
 break
```

should be this:

```
if topping == "quit":
    break
```

Very subtle, but very important in Python.

Comment: Indentation _is_ the problem, but _this part_ is fine (or irrelevant).